# Android Options menu not display well on Google Maps (Api v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-optionsmenu

In an activity I have a fragment that contains a google maps. On the top I have a button that if clicked showing an options menu.
However the menu is not shown correctly. It appears transparent and are displayed only two of three option items.
Have you any idea about this behavior?
Thanks at all in advance for any reply.

minSdkVersion 15

This is my menu:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/zoom" android:title="Zoom sulla mia posizione" android:orderInCategory="1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/centra" android:title="Centra sulla mia posizione" android:orderInCategory="2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/mappa" android:title="Mappa iniziale" android:orderInCategory="3" />
</menu>
```

This is my layout for the activity with the map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
  android:layout_above="@+id/actnavbar"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my activity class (maps.class):

```
    package testapp;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class maps extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private MyDatabase mDbHelper;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LatLngBounds bounds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_italia);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        ImageView menuButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_button); 
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              Vibrator vibrazione = (Vibrator) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
//              vibrazione.vibrate(25);         

                openOptionsMenu();              
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
     * MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to install/update the Google Play services APK on
     * their device.
     * <p>
     * A user can return to this Activity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the Activity may not have been
     * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be stopped or
     * paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this method in
     * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            //if (mMap != null) {
            //    setUpMap();
            //}
            mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMapType(1);

        CameraUpdate update = null;

        //bound dei centri
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        Float latitudine = 39.40;
        Float longitudione = 20.10;
        LatLng coordinateCentro = new LatLng(latitudine, longitudine);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(coordinateCentro)
           .title("test")
           .snippet("AAA, BBBB")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        builder.include(coordinateCentro);

        //setMarkerUserPosition();
        bounds = builder.build();

        int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){        
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_italia, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.zoom:
                zoom();             
                return true;
            case R.id.centra:
                centra();
                return true;
            case R.id.mappa:
                mappaIniziale();
                return true;
            default:
                return true;

        }
    }

    public void setMarkerUserPosition(){
        /*Setta il marker azzurro nella posizione attuale dell utente*/
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Italia.this);
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){
             double myLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
             double myLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
             LatLng coordinateAttuali = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(coordinateAttuali)
             .title("Posizione Attuale")
             //.snippet()
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
         }
    }

    private void zoom() {
        Log.d("Menu", "ZOOM-----");
        float myTilt = mMap.getCameraPosition().tilt;           //TILT indica quanto la visuale sia "schiacciata"--> default 0
        float myBearing = mMap.getCameraPosition().bearing;     //BEARING indica la "rotazione" della visuale--> default 0
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Italia.this);        
         // check if GPS enabled
         if(gps.canGetLocation()){
             double myLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
             double myLongitude = gps.getLongitude();            
             float myZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
             float newZoom;
             if ((myZoom + 4) < 20)
                 newZoom = myZoom + 4;
             else
                 newZoom = 20;

            //setta la giusta posizione(mia posizione) e livello di zoom iniziale della mappa
            LatLng mieCoordinate = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
            CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition(mieCoordinate, (float) newZoom, myTilt, myBearing); 
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));
          //stop GPS
            gps.stopUsingGPS();
         }else{
             // can't get location  // GPS or Network is not enabled  // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
             gps.showSettingsAlert();
         }
    }

    private void centra() {
        Log.d("Menu", "CENTRA-----");
        float myZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        float myTilt = mMap.getCameraPosition().tilt;           //TILT indica quanto la visuale sia "schiacciata"--> default 0
        float myBearing = mMap.getCameraPosition().bearing;     //BEARING indica la "rotazione" della visuale--> default 0
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Italia.this);        
         // check if GPS enabled
         if(gps.canGetLocation()){
            double myLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double myLongitude = gps.getLongitude();            



            //setta la giusta posizione(mia posizione) e livello di zoom iniziale della mappa
            LatLng mieCoordinate = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
            CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition(mieCoordinate, myZoom, myTilt, myBearing); 
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));
            //stop GPS
            gps.stopUsingGPS();
         }else{
            // can't get location   // GPS or Network is not enabled  // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
         }
    }

    private void mappaIniziale()
    {
        Log.d("Menu", "MAPPAINIZIALE***-----");
        /*LatLng coordinateRoma = new LatLng(42.5, 12.483333);
        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition(coordinateRoma, (float) 5, (float) 0, (float) 0); 
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));*/
        mMap.setMapType(1);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to make your activity class inherit from `ActionBarActivity` or `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`, which is `important`.

Also, you may change your `AppTheme` as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

It will show the `ActionBar`which contains a `menu` in it.

Also, you can refer an example source code from my Github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want a FragmentActivty with an action bar. If using appcompact you `must` use `ActionBarActivity`. Dont worry that FragmentActivty is already included in ActionBarActivity.

Ps: This is just my opinion but if you wants a full customable actionbar think in using Toolbar. With appcompact you cant use it to the minimum SDK that you are using.